# java defining list/object with null or new?

Tags: java

I am new to java have basic doubt on below code.

1) code for getting list.

```
public List < User > getUsers() {

    List < User > users = null;

    try {

        users = UserDAO.getUsers();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return users;
}
```

My question is what is the best approach in defining List or object?

1. `List<User> users=null;`
2. `List<User> users=new List<User>();`

what is the best approach and why?

2) Similar code for object like below:

```
public User getUser() {

    user user = null;

    try {

        user = UserDAO.getUser();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return user;
}
```

1. `User user=null;`
2. `User user=new User();`

what is the best approach and why?

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: Also, please learn to indent your code.  You need to take some time to read about Java Style ... if you are going to ask other people to read your code.

Comment: `List<User> users=new List<User>()` will not compile (**yes, Java is compiled!**), since you can't instantiate an interface, i.e. `List`. Did you mean `= new ArrayList<User>()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to say which is "better" of the alternatives you proposed.  It depends on what the behavior of `getUsers()` / `getUser()` are *required to be* when there is an exception.  That is a debate between the API designer and the API user(s).  There will be **opinion** involved, and discussion of efficiency versus maintainability trade-offs ...

But in both questions, if I was designing the API I would do it differently to both of your alternatives.

---

Question 1:

If I was designing the API, I would probably write it like this:

```
public List <User> getUsers() throws SomeException {
    return UserDAO.getUsers();
}
```

If it was necessary to deal with certain exceptions inside the getter, I would do this:

```
public List <User> getUsers() {
    try {
        return UserDAO.getUsers();
    } catch (SomeException ex) {    // Not 'Exception' !
        // log the exception properly. Not a printStacktrace call!
        return new ArrayList<>();   // Not 'null'
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Don't catch `Exception`.  Really bad idea.
2. Don't log using printstacktrace.
3. Returning `null` to indicate a failure is liable to lead to NPEs.  If the caller needs to know if there was a failure, that's what exceptions are for.

---

Question 2:

Similar principles.  The Java 8 way to do the second form would be:

```
public Optional<User> getUser() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(UserDAO.getUser());
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
        // log the exception 
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Prior to Java 8, the best way to avoid returning `null` would be to declare a `User` instance that denotes "no user" and return that.

```
public static final User NO_USER = new User();  // preferably immutable!

public User getUser() {
    try {
        return UserDAO.getUser();
    } catch (SomeException ex) {
        // log the exception 
        return NO_USER;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on how your code is supposed to behave. You need to decide what your code behavior should be in the event the attempt to get the user list generates an exception. If it should carry on with an empty list then you want to use `new ArrayList<>()` but if you want you want to alert the user or stop the program in an exception then you should use `= null` and then use conditional statements to check for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**:

`List<User> users = null;` is not creating any object, just creating a reference to nothing.

`List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();` is creating an object, an empty list in this case.

In your example you should probably use `List<User> users = null;` because there is no reason to create an empty object since `UserDAO.getUsers();` will already create and return an object.

Unless you want to return an empty list instead of `null` when an exception occurs; in that case then `List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();` would make sense.

**Case 2**:

`User user = null;` is not creating any object, just creating a reference to nothing.

`User user = new User();` is creating an object, a default instance of `User`.

Same as before, but in this case I would say that `User user = new User();` does not make a lot of sense. If an exception occurs it might be OK to return an empty list, but I don't see a reason to return a default instance of an `User` object instead of `null`.